# How to get groupid when have userid - liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have userid 
and how to get groupid 
exactly groupid and userid in table users_groups of liferay 
==== 
ex: 
- userA - siteA - groupA 
- userb - SiteB - GroupB

when i use userB, login to portal from SiteA 
how can get groupB when userB stay in SiteA?

Answer (score 0):

You can get `groupId` from `ThemeDisplay`, for example.

If I understand your question correctly, you should use `...Util`, something like that:

`UserGroupLocalServiceUtil.getUsers()`.

If we have misunderstating - add to your question more details.